# View data in Server Explorer (LocalDB) VS2012

Tags: visual-studio-2012, localdb

I created a LocalDB and added it to my solution. I am using the Entity Framework.

I can add and retreive data from the localdb (i'm running Release), but the database is being copied to the bin/Release folder.

I want to view the data in my Server Explorer that has been added. Is this even possible?

How to do it?

Answer (score 7):

Ok, I wanted to do something similar. The way you can see data added to the localDB, is the following, On your solution explorer right click on the database - example(mydb.mdf), then click on open, a window should pop up asking you for the database source and file name, it should have default values just click ok. Now you can see the localDB on the server explorer. All you have to do now is look for a table and create a new query - example (select * from mytablename). You should be able to see the data retrieved by the query. Hope this help

Comment: How do you "create a new query" from the Server Explorer?